# How to extend the domain of this variable in this function?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion

so recently, i have been thinking about the following question:

if there exist $\frac{{d^n}}{{dx^n}} g(x) = n \frac{{d^n}}{{dx^n}} f(x)$
can we express it as some $h(f(x))$?

so the answer is yes. We can express it as $(x-a)\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

by transforming the function $f(x)$ into a Taylor series, and then making some manipulations.

but more generally, we can express it like this:

$$\int_a^x g(x) \ dx = (x-a)f(x) - \int_a^x f(x) \ dx$$

and if we can express any g(x) as a taylor sum that looks like this
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(a)}{n!} \ (x-a)^n$$
then by the formula $\int_a^x g(x) \ dx = (x-a)f(x) - \int_a^x f(x) \ dx$, it's just equal to:
$$(x-a)\frac{d}{dx} \underbrace{\circ \ (x-a)\frac{d}{dx} \circ \ldots \circ f}_{k \text{ times}} (x) \text{, for } \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
(for $k<0$ it's just the inverse $\int_a^x \frac {f(x)}{(x-a)}\ dx$)

and there is my question

**can we extend the domain of k to real numbers or even complex numbers?**

I was trying to do this with the same approach like Euler did with gamma function or harmonic numbers, and also i was thinking about transforming a function into logarithm, so we could get the power out from the sum. I Would like to ask for help, if anyone could expand it , or give a hint for a solution, I would really appreciate it. Im still in high school, and the level of math like bell polynomials or some higher level calculations are just too difficult for me.

Thanks for reading and giving attention.

Comment: I think that there is something wrong... The [taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) should be $g(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{g^{(n)}(a)}{n!} \cdot (x-a)^n \right] = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{n \cdot f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n \right]$. Why does your taylor series start with $n = 1$, where does your $k$ come from and why is there $x$ in $f^{(n)}(x)$ (inside the sum)?

Comment: oh i see, sry my bad it should be $ f(a)$, and it's starts with n=1, because like you can see, when n=0, the first term is just 0, and when it's 1/n^k, it's undefined. But when it's equal n=1 we don't have this problem. might look like it's kind of illegal, but when you gonna calculate it, it's actually equal to the function.

Comment: and about why it's n^k there: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(a)}{n!} \ (x-a)^n \ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n*n^(k-1) \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(a)}{n!} \ (x-a)^n \ = (x-a)\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\text{, where } \frac{d^n}{dx^n}g(x) = n*\frac{d^n}{dx^n}h(x)$$
but we know that h(x) = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^(k-1) \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(a)}{n!} \ (x-a)^n$, and we can repeat the process, so it's $$(x-a)\frac{d}{dx} \underbrace{\circ \ (x-a)\frac{d}{dx} \circ \ldots \circ f}_{k \text{ times}} (x)$$
and this is why.